# Generating the resource url for swagger without /api/v4 prefix to resource - C# dotnet webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an api where I defined routes for a resource using attribute routing.

```cs
[Route("api/document/v3/[controller]")]
public class DocumentController : ControllerBase
```

This results in the generated swagger having `api/document/v3/` as a prefix before the resource path

[Generated swagger resource path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFks.png)

I would like the `api/document/v3/` to be part of the base url and the controller to only have `/document` so the generated swagger will have `/document` as the path for the resource or collection.

Here is an example image of what I want

[Path as I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Zth.png)

Comment: Would that not be located in your `startup` file or the swashbuckle file?

Comment: Yes, I have to change the swashbuckle config. I thought it had something to do with attribute routing.